# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Call not returning Json data from controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application where I would like to call a controller method via Ajax and have it return an array from the controller in Json format.

**Controller**:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{ 

 public JsonResult GetArray() {

 // Code for getting array here

 // Convert array to JSON data
 return Json(new { Items =  ArrayName.ToList()});

 }
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/Home/GetArray",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
            $(".container").append('<p>'+ result +'</p>');
         }
      error: function(){
         alert("Data was not fetched properly");
         }
});
```

Whenever I make this Ajax call, an error is always returned.  I have set breakpoints within my controller and the values are being stored properly but I'm not sure why it won't reach the success function.

Comment: Exactly what was the error?

Comment: You need to add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, or use a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe MVC denies GET requests. You have to specifically allow get requests.  Along with your json data, pass JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet into your return statement.

```
 return Json(new { Items =  ArrayName.ToList()},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's help full for you, you can use this return type

return Json(objResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);